# How to search for words that contain all the letters from the array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of words, for example -

```
   const array = ["apple", "apricot", "avocado"];
```

I want to look for the words that contain

1. All the letters from the array
2. to be in order.
   If I'm writing -

```
const L = ["a", "o", "c"];
   const out = arrayF.filter ((el) => L.every ((letter) => el.includes (letter)));
```

Although he is looking for me all the letters, but if for example I will write-

```
   const L = ["a", "a", "a"];
```

- This's causing me some problems.

1. Even if I searched 3 times for the letter a he will also find me the one who has only once the letter.
2. When I search according to -

```
const L = ["a", "o", "c"];
```

He also finds me "apricot" even if the "o" after the "c"

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const 
  array = ["apple", "apricot", "avocado"],
  L = ["a", "o", "c"];

// iterate over array
const out = array.filter(el => {
  // initialize count to zero
  let count = 0;
  // iterate over current element's letters
  el.split('').forEach(letter => {
    // if current letter in L is letter, increment count
    if(L[count] === letter) { count++; }
  });
  // after iterating, check if all L letters were found in order
  return count === L.length;
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: this solution is naive as `forEach` does not offer an option for early exit. it will continue iterating even after a false answer can be determined. If list of words to search for is significantly large, this would result in a tremendous amount of wasted time/space. See Jonas's answer for a more optimal solution.

Comment: @mulan not quite, at the end of my solution `target` is fully traversed, just like the algorithm presented here traverses `el` fully. I do hope though that the engine can optimize `indexOf` better than `el.split("").forEach` and thus it'll perform better on average. Pure speculation though. Your conclusion is correct for the "true case"

Comment: Thank you,
you helped me alot. Another question - if the search is from one word, and not from an array, how do I change the code to make it work?

Comment: @R-S you can keep using the same solution, or check ``String#charAt``.

Comment: @JonasWilms if you use a function you can `return` to break out of the loop. And yes I would imagine `indexOf` is more efficient than building a new array and stepping through it one by one..

Answer (score 2):

`String.prototype.indexOf` takes a second parameter, the index where to start searching.

```
 const search = ["a", "o", "c"];
 const target = "aoaoc";

 let targetPos = 0;

for(const searchChar of search) {
    const nextPos = target.indexOf(searchChar, targetPos );
   if (nextPos === -1) {
     return false;
   }
   targetPos = nextPos + 1;
 }

 return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to achieve what you want I think that `every()` is just to simplistic for you. How about something like this:

```
const wordsArray = ["apple", "apricot", "avocado"];
const lettersArray = ["a", "o", "c"];

const out = wordsArray.filter(word => {
  let truncatedWord = word;
  for (const [i, letter] of lettersArray.entries()) {
    if (truncatedWord.includes(letter)) {
      if (i === lettersArray.length -1) {
        return true;
      }
      truncatedWord = truncatedWord.substr(truncatedWord.indexOf(letter) + 1)
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [RegExp#test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with a regular expression created from the search array. To ensure this doesn't break when special characters are included in the search array you'll need to escape the search strings before hand, here using the [escape function listed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping).

```js
const
  filterByHasCharsInOrder = (target, search) => {
    const regexString = search.map(s => escapeRegExp(s)).join('.*');
    const regex = new RegExp(regexString);
    // concat into array allows array or string targets to be passed
    return [].concat(target).filter(s => regex.test(s));
  },

  array = ["apple", "apricot", "avocado"];

// Testing
console.log('["a", "a", "a"]: ',
  filterByHasCharsInOrder(array, ["a", "a", "a"])
);

console.log('["a", "o", "c"]: ',
  filterByHasCharsInOrder(array, ["a", "v", "o"])
);

// pass single string
console.log('["a", "[", "o"]: ',
  filterByHasCharsInOrder("avo.ca[do", ["a", "[", "o"])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  // see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping
  function escapeRegExp(string) {
    return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
  }
</script>
```